# Android project unable to build on update to android studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

its showing on build console:

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Booklify\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:1434: error:  inner element must either be a resource reference or empty.

Command: C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\fc444429c9ac9f1db8d9bb3790bf9413\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Booklify\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\Booklify\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2

Answer (score 0):

Please write this command on terminal of your project in android studio.

gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue. Please have a look into your values.xml at the given line. There will most likely be some id like

`<item name="abc" type="id"/>` which has not `/>` but a value like `<item name="abc" type="id">abc</item>`

This wasn't allowed since the beginning but now it also causes a compilation error. So remove the value and the closing tag and add the slash before the `>`

Edit: Of course you need to do this change in the ids.xml (or any other related file) not in the values.xml inside the build folder. But this file gives you the hint where to look.